# Disable videoElements while another video on the page is playing

Tags: javascript, limesurvey

I've been working on a survey where there are 14 short animations. After you watch the short animation you can answer a question about it rating the clip from 0 - 5. The radio elements are disabled until you've watched the clip, but now I also want to disable the other videoElements while one clip is playing. Namely because otherwise you can just move your mouse across the screen and the videos will play and get enabled after you've "watched" them even though you didn't really pay attention to them. I see related questions on the forum but they are about stopping another video when you press play, this is not what I want.

My code is:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var videoElements = document.getElementsByClassName("videos");
    var radioElements = document.querySelectorAll(".answer-item.radio-item input[type=radio]");

    // Disable alle radio elementen.
    for (let radioElement of radioElements) {
      // radio elements can't be clicked
      radioElement.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }

    // Add listeners voor alle video elementen.
     for (let videoElement of videoElements) {
          // On mouseover start the video.
      videoElement.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
        var video = event.currentTarget;
        video.play();
        if (event.currentTarget.currentTime < 1){
            videoElements.setAttribute("disabled","disabled")
        }
      });

      // While playing, check if timestamp >  0.8, if so, enable the inputs.
      videoElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', (event) => {
        if (event.currentTarget.currentTime > 0.8) {
          // Zoek de index (hoeveelste video) van deze video.
          let index = Array.from(videoElements).indexOf(event.currentTarget);

          if (index !== -1) {
            // Zoek de 5 matchende radio elementen.
            let startIndex = index == 0 ? 0 : index * 5;
            let endIndex = startIndex + 5;
            let fiveRadioElements = Array.from(radioElements).slice(startIndex, endIndex);

            // Enable the 5 radio elements that belong to this video.
            for (let radioElement of fiveRadioElements) {
              radioElement.removeAttribute("disabled");
            }
          }
        }
      })
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: one method maybe not add the mouseOver eventListener until the previous video has been seen? In your case, add the listener for video element at next index along with enabling the radioElements

Comment: But I need the mouseOver to enable the first video so I can't move it to somewhere else. Also, I can't specify a certain video as the first video, because there is no first video. What I mean by this, I can't say: video1.onClick etc. and then make the rest mouseOver for example

Comment: Why not add a validation, before enabling one video, make sure the previous radio elements are answered or previous videos are fully executed?

Comment: Seems logical even though I'm not familiar with this, do you have any examples?

Answer (score 0):

It has been fixed thanks to my good HappyLinks. 
For those interested:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var videoElements = document.getElementsByClassName("videos");
    var radioElements = document.querySelectorAll(".answer-item.radio-item input[type=radio]");

    // Disable alle radio elementen.
    for (let radioElement of radioElements) {
      // radio elements can't be clicked
      radioElement.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }

    // Add listeners voor alle video elementen. --> this is in comments because we want the clip to continue playing at mouseout
    var isVideoPlaying = false;
    for (let videoElement of videoElements) {
      // On mouseover start the video.
      videoElement.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
        var video = event.currentTarget;
        if (!isVideoPlaying) {
          video.play();
          isVideoPlaying = true;
        }
      });

      // While playing, check if timestamp > 0.8, if so, enable the inputs.
      videoElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', (event) => {
        if (event.currentTarget.currentTime > 0.8) {
          // Zoek de index (hoeveelste video) van deze video.
          let index = Array.from(videoElements).indexOf(event.currentTarget);

          if (index !== -1) {
            // Zoek de 5 matchende radio elementen.
            let startIndex = index == 0 ? 0 : index * 5;
            let endIndex = startIndex + 5;
            let fiveRadioElements = Array.from(radioElements).slice(startIndex, endIndex);

            // Enable the 5 radio elements that belong to this video.
            for (let radioElement of fiveRadioElements) {
              radioElement.removeAttribute("disabled");
            }

          }
        }
      });

      videoElement.addEventListener('ended', (event) => {
        isVideoPlaying = false;
      });
    }
  });
```